# Adding TextField to AlertController breaks AlertController

Tags: iphone, swift, alert, textfield, uialertcontroller

I am currently trying to open up an AlertController with a TextField inside. When running

```
let configAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Configure Add-On", message: "Enter Your Add-On Name:", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

configAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      // Handle Input          
}))

present(configAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

everything works fine, but as soon as I add the TextField

```
configAlert.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Name"
}
```

the Alert takes about 10 times longer to open, instantly dismisses, and I get this error in the console spammed about 30 times:

```
2017-11-26 13:04:08.985783-0500 MinelyMod[380:14792] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UISplitViewController: 0x147e0a6a0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

Here is the completed AlertController thats failing

```
let configAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Configure Add-On", message: "Enter Your Add-On Name:", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

configAlert.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Name"
}

configAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    // Handle Input            
}))

present(configAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What kind of event triggers your code to be called? It looks like it's happening in the middle of the presentation animation for some other controller.

Comment: Make sure you call `present(_: UIViewController)` method from the main thread. Btw you should also post your handle input code.

Comment: I have copied and pasted it in a new project and it worked fine for me. I am using xcode 8.3.  Try that and see if it works there and if so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @LeoDabus It crashes without handling the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in
        let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        // do something with textField
    }))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Search"
    })

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: code only answers are not recommended. Please explain what the OP was doing wrong...